# ReactPHP and Promises

Tags: php, asynchronous, promise, reactphp

I'm trying to understand the concept of Promises using ReactPHP

```
$app = function ($request, $response) use ($redis, $config) {

    $promise = React\Promise\all(
        array(
            AsyncGetUser(),
            AsyncGetDB(),
            AsyncGetTemplate()
        )
    )->then(function ($res) {
        $result = ParseTemplate($user, $template, $whatever);
    }

    \React\Promise\resolve($promise);


    $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
    $response->end($result);

}

$http->on('request', $app);
```

But `$response` is sent before `$result` is ready.
How can do something like await for `$promise` so I send `$result` properly ?

I've tried to move `$response->end` to `another->then()` section but then I don't get any response in browser (i.e. the script gets a result when $app = function is finished already).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know reactphp at all, but if promises work like promises in JS for example, seems like you need to write the response in the `->then` where you have a result!

```
$app = function ($request, $response) use ($redis, $config) {
    $promise = React\Promise\all(
        array(
            AsyncGetUser(),
            AsyncGetDB(),
            AsyncGetTemplate()
        )
    )->then(function ($res) {
        $result = ParseTemplate($user, $template, $whatever);
        $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
        $response->end($result);
    }
}

$http->on('request', $app);
```

Note: the following line in your code

```
\React\Promise\resolve($promise);
```

makes no sense. `\React\Promise\resolve` doesn't "resolve the promise" as you seem to think, it creates and returns a resolved promise - which you discard!